# Java XML Transformer

Tags: java, xml, transformer-model

I have been trying to create an XML document, but keep getting a Null Pointer Exception error, and I have spent several hours trying to figure out why.

The path is correct because it works when reading the file.

Main:

```
    public static final String PATH = "res/config.xml";

public Main() {

}
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new WriteConfig(PATH);
}
```

WriteConfig:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteConfig {
Document dom;
Element e = null;
String name;
String gender;
String race;
String cclass;

public WriteConfig(String xml) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();       
    try {
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element mainRootElement = dom.createElement("character");

        e = dom.createElement("name");
        e.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(name));
        mainRootElement.appendChild(e);

        e = dom.createElement("gender");
        e.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(gender));
        mainRootElement.appendChild(e);

        e = dom.createElement("race");
        e.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(race));
        mainRootElement.appendChild(e);

        dom.appendChild(mainRootElement);

        try {
            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "res/config.dtd");
            tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            DOMSource dSource = new DOMSource(dom);
            StreamResult sResult = new StreamResult(xml);
            tr.transform(dSource, sResult);
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

Error:

```
    ERROR:  ''
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:752)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:357)
    at bamberger.com.engine.WriteConfig.<init>(WriteConfig.java:64)
    at bamberger.com.engine.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1612)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:244)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:136)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:699)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743)
    ... 3 more
---------
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1612)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:244)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:136)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:699)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:357)
    at bamberger.com.engine.WriteConfig.<init>(WriteConfig.java:64)
    at bamberger.com.engine.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

WriteConfig.java:64

```
tr.transform(dSource, sResult);
```

Thanks!

Comment: have spent several hours => And you don't used a debugger to see where is the null? I think you have just wasted your time :/

Comment: It is bad style to implement processing in the constructor. Besides, if you talk about Exceptions, show the exception and map the line numbers. In your sample code all strings are null.

Comment: Check this out: [What is a NullPointerException, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) If that doesn't help, post the error. It'll make it easier to distinguish the problem in the code

Comment: I know what a NullPointerException is, but I still cannot figure out what is wrong with this code. I posted the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `String name;` in `WriteConfig` before trying to use it for `e.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(name));`. Initialize the `name` variable to fix the error.

Comment: _bangs head against keyboard._ Thank you so much. I cannot believe I missed that. I was planning to get those strings through another method once I got the code working, and I just forgot to initialize them

Comment: We've all been there :P Next time, use `System.out.println(name);` to check if a variable is null. Any variable that is not primitive can be null

Answer (score 0):

```
String name;
String gender;
String race;
String cclass;
```

must be initialize variable before use it.

```
         //Decarle variable
        String name;
        String gender;
        String race;
        String cclass;


        //Initialize and set value
        name = "EwokHugz";
        gender = "female";
        race = "10";
        cclass = "XML Programming";
```